REAL80 size and checking its availability in Meson build system
Meson is venerable build system, but its Fortran support is limited when compared to C.
For example, in C, Meson has compiler.has_type(...), compiler.has_function(...),
compiler.has_library(...), compiler.has_member(...). compiler.sizeof(...), and ...,
but in Fortran, those functions will not work.
I need to check available INTEGER and REAL kinds and pass macros like HAS_REAL80, HAS_REAL128, ...
to the preprocessor. It is easy to check availability of the INT128 and REAL128 kinds:
fc = meson.get_compiler('fortran')
has_int128 = fc.compiles(
  'use iso_fortran_env, only: INT128; end',
  name: 'has INT128 kind')
has_real128 = fc.compiles(
  'use iso_fortran_env, only: REAL128; end',
  name: 'has REAL128 kind')

For REAL80, I had to retrieve all available real kinds:
real_kinds = fc.run(
  'use iso_fortran_env; print *, real_kinds; end',
  name: 'real kinds').stdout().split()

Then I tried to check REAL80 availability, by checking storage size of each real kind found by above snippet:
has_real80 = false
foreach real_kind: real_kinds
  run = fc.run(
    'print *, storage_size(0.0_@0@); end'.format(real_kind),
    name: 'storage size of real(@0@)'.format(real_kind)
  )
  if run.stdout().strip() == '80'
    has_real80 = true
  endif
endforeach

But it turns out that storage_size (0.0_REAL80) is not the expected 80 bits. It is 128 bit in both gfortran and new flang (It is not available in classic flang and Intel compilers!), and my Meson snippet does not work.
print *, storage_size (0.0_10)
! result is 128 by both gfortran and flang-new!

Questions:

Size of REAL(80) is 128. Why?
What is the best way to check availability of REAL80?

For the first question, I think, memory alignment and optimization are the answers. But if alignment matters
in this case, why storage_size (0_INT16) is 16?
For the second question, I wrote a code that checks precision and range of all real kinds
and select REAL80 as a real kind with greater precision than REAL64 and smaller precision than REAL128.
But I think simpler solution must exists for the problem.

Here is minimal working meson.build file (to try it just run FC=/path/to/fortran/compiler meson setup build)
project('myproject', 'fortran',
  version: '0.1.0',
  meson_version: '>= 1.2.0',
  default_options: [
    'buildtype=debugoptimized',
    'warning_level=3'
  ],
  license: 'GPL-3.0-or-Later'
)

# Get the Fortran compiler and Fypp preprocessor
fc = meson.get_compiler('fortran')
fypp = find_program('fypp')

# Check avbailability of the INT128 and REAL128 kinds
has_int128 = fc.compiles(
  'use iso_fortran_env, only: INT128; end',
  name: 'has INT128 kind')
has_real128 = fc.compiles(
  'use iso_fortran_env, only: REAL128; end',
  name: 'has REAL128 kind')

# Retrive all available real kinds
real_kinds = fc.run(
  'use iso_fortran_env; print *, real_kinds; end',
  name: 'real kinds').stdout().split()

# Check which real kinds is REAL80?
has_real80 = false
foreach real_kind: real_kinds
  run = fc.run(
    'print *, storage_size(0.0_@0@); end'.format(real_kind),
    name: 'storage size of real(@0@)'.format(real_kind)
  )
  if run.stdout().strip() == '80'
    has_real80 = true
  endif
endforeach

# Print summary of findings
summary({
   'Fortran Compiler': fc.get_id() + ' ' + fc.version(),
   'Linker'          : fc.get_linker_id(),
   'CPU'             : host_machine.cpu() + ' (' + host_machine.endian() + ' endian)',
   'Operating System': host_machine.system(),
   'Has INT128?'     : has_int128,
   'Has REAL80?'     : has_real80,
   'Has REAL128?'    : has_real128
}, section: 'Summary')

And the output of meson setup build for gfortran, flang and ifx compilers:
gfortran 14.1 output:
The Meson build system
Version: 1.4.1
Source dir: /home/gmt/Projects/myproject
Build dir: /home/gmt/Projects/myproject/build
Build type: native build
Project name: myproject
Project version: 0.1.0
Fortran compiler for the host machine: gfortran (gcc 14.1.1 "GNU Fortran (GCC) 14.1.1 20240522")
Fortran linker for the host machine: gfortran ld.bfd 2.42.0
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Program fypp found: YES (/usr/bin/fypp)
Checking if "has INT128 kind" compiles: NO 
Checking if "has REAL128 kind" compiles: YES 
Checking if "real kinds" runs: YES
Checking if "storage size of real(4)" runs: YES
Checking if "storage size of real(8)" runs: YES
Checking if "storage size of real(10)" runs: YES
Checking if "storage size of real(16)" runs: YES
Build targets in project: 0

myproject 0.1.0

  Summary
    Fortran Compiler: gcc 14.1.1
    Linker          : ld.bfd
    CPU             : x86_64 (little endian)
    Operating System: linux
    Has INT128?     : false
    Has REAL80?     : false
    Has REAL128?    : true

Found ninja-1.12.1 at /usr/bin/ninja

Classic flang 16 (AOCC 4.2.0) output:
The Meson build system
Version: 1.4.1
Source dir: /home/gmt/Projects/myproject
Build dir: /home/gmt/Projects/myproject/build
Build type: native build
Project name: myproject
Project version: 0.1.0
Fortran compiler for the host machine: /opt/aocc/4.2.0/bin/flang (flang 16.0.3 "AMD clang version 16.0.3 (CLANG: AOCC_4.2.0-Build#89 2023_12_13)")
Fortran linker for the host machine: /opt/aocc/4.2.0/bin/flang ld.lld 16.0.3
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Program fypp found: YES (/usr/bin/fypp)
Checking if "has INT128 kind" compiles: NO 
Checking if "has REAL128 kind" compiles: YES 
Checking if "real kinds" runs: YES
Checking if "storage size of real(4)" runs: YES
Checking if "storage size of real(8)" runs: YES
Checking if "storage size of real(16)" runs: YES
Build targets in project: 0

myproject 0.1.0

  Summary
    Fortran Compiler: flang 16.0.3
    Linker          : ld.lld
    CPU             : x86_64 (little endian)
    Operating System: linux
    Has INT128?     : false
    Has REAL80?     : false
    Has REAL128?    : true

Found ninja-1.12.1 at /usr/bin/ninja

Intel LLVM based Fortran compiler 2024.1 output:
The Meson build system
Version: 1.4.1
Source dir: /home/gmt/Projects/myproject
Build dir: /home/gmt/Projects/myproject/build
Build type: native build
Project name: myproject
Project version: 0.1.0
Fortran compiler for the host machine: /opt/oneapi/compiler/latest/bin/ifx (intel-llvm 2024.1.0 "ifx (IFX) 2024.1.0 20240308")
Fortran linker for the host machine: /opt/oneapi/compiler/latest/bin/ifx ld.bfd 2.42.0
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Program fypp found: YES (/usr/bin/fypp)
Checking if "has INT128 kind" compiles: NO 
Checking if "has REAL128 kind" compiles: YES 
Checking if "real kinds" runs: YES
Checking if "storage size of real(4)" runs: YES
Checking if "storage size of real(8)" runs: YES
Checking if "storage size of real(16)" runs: YES
Build targets in project: 0

myproject 0.1.0

  Summary
    Fortran Compiler: intel-llvm 2024.1.0
    Linker          : ld.bfd
    CPU             : x86_64 (little endian)
    Operating System: linux
    Has INT128?     : false
    Has REAL80?     : false
    Has REAL128?    : true

Found ninja-1.12.1 at /usr/bin/ninja

EDIT 1
It seems __float80 size in GCC is 128 bits too!
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  __float80 a;
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(a));
  return 0;
}

Result is 16 bytes or 128 bits!!!!

The available kind type parameters can be found in the iso_fortran_env intrinsic module in the array REAL_KINDS.  You've seem to have found this.  The named constants REAL32, REAL64, and REAL128 have nothing to do with precision.  These simply note the number of bits required to store that kind of REAL entity.  REAL(REAL32) occupies 32 bits.  It says nothing about precision (in Fortran parlance that would be DIGITS()).  Note, if you're using gfortran, it defines a set of preprocessing macros for you, e.g., __GFC_REAL_10__.

Thank you @steve about __GFC_REAL_10__. REAL_KINDS of iso_fortran_env don't help for writing generic codes for example for r4, r8, r10 and r16. We need them in pre-processor level. I need something portable between major compilers using fypp or even fpp or cpp. So I need to inquire them using build system and pass them to the preprocessor.

Understood.  The only way I know how to solve the problem is to write a Fortran code to data mine iso_fortran_env for real_kinds array.  The code generates two files.  The first is a module that defines the available kind types and the second is a header file that defines C macros.

The INT128 test looks incorrect. For example, for gfortran 13.2 INT128 undefined, but integer, parameter :: k128 = selected_int_kind(38) can be used quite well. And the operator print *, k128, storage_size(0_k128) outputs 16 128

For Intel processors, the types are real(10) and real(16) differ, although usually storage_size(0.0_10) == storage_size(0.0_16) == 16. Usually, real(10) is significantly faster than real(16), but it depends on using SIMD for 32 or 64 bit floating types. For detect real(10)  it is necessary to check digits(0.0_10) == 64.

Thank you @Serge3leo, digits(0.0_10) == 64 works for both 80x87 and 68881/2 FPUs.

As for the alignment issue, contemporary processors typically want data to aligned on a power-of-two boundary, called "naturally aligned". For data types that are a power-of-two size, like most integer and floating point types are, this is doable without empty padding bits. But the smallest power-of-two size >= 80 bits is 128 bits, hence if you want your data aligned on a power-of-two boundary you need the padding bits.

Thank you. @janneb Good explanation. This makes sense. However sizeof __float80 == 16 or 128 bit extended reals on x86_64 is mandated by x86_64 SysV ABI. See steve comments @ this question

And the reason why the ABI is like that is the explanation given by by @janneb. Note that a compiler is absolutely free to follow another convention: it will work as long as the compiled code is not linked with libraries that follow a different convention.
